# Managing identity/primary key across servers

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, identity

I'm in the middle of designing a new database that will need to support replication and I'm stuck on the decision what to choose as my primary key.

In our current database for primary key we use two int columns, first column is identity and the other is used to describe on which server the row is inserted. Now I want to avoid using two columns for primary key, and just use one column instead. So far I have two way of doing this:

1. Use GUID for my primary key

   This one will ensure that there is always a unique key across any number of servers. What I don't like with this one, is that the GUID is 16bytes in size, and when used for foreign key across many tables it will waste space. Also it is harder to use it when writing queries, and it will slower to query.
2. Use the int or bigint, and manually specify the seed and increment value for every table on each server. For example if there is two servers, the X table on the first server will start from number 1, and on second server it will start from number 2, each will increment by 2. So there would be (1,3,5,...) on first, and (2,4,6,...) on second server. The good thing with this design is that it is easier to use when writing queries, it's fast, and it use less space for foreign keys. Bad thing is that we never know how many servers will be running so it's harder to tell what will be the increment value. Also it's harder to manage the schema change on server.

What is the best practice for managing multiple servers, and what's the best way, if any, to do in this kind if situations?

Comment: But even two `int` fields are still only 8 byte (instead of 16 for a GUID) .... also: two `int` make a much better clustering key than a GUID - [GUIDs as clustering key in SQL Server are a horribly bad choice](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)

Comment: Another alternative is to use composite keys, with one column for the server, and the other column for the server-specific int. (A GUID is 16 bytes; not one of those bytes is wasted. You might be able to come up with a smaller key, but that still doesn't mean a GUID is wasteful. It's just a little wider than every narrower key. *Waste* is just a bad term here, because it limits your thinking.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a good one, and one that is asked often.

From a maintenance perspective, I would absolutely go with GUIDS. They are there for a reason.
Somewhere along the line you might run into complex operations moving and re-replicating your data, and then the other options can make it a little more complex than it needs to be.

There is a very nice short read about the various options here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011.aspx

As for the Replication part - if done properly, there are no real headaches with replication.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Found a more simple/manual method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218986/sql-server-2000-2005-identity-column-replication). Involves using [NOT FOR REPLICATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152529%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and staggering identity seed values as you mentioned in comments.

**Original:**

Your best bet is something like the second option listed. Assign identity ranges for the replication publisher and subscriber instances, then turn on automatic range management.

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543.aspx) discusses options for managing identity columns in replication, and [enabling identity range management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146907.aspx) is discussed here.

Since you don't know how many servers will be in the replication pool, you may need to reconfigure article properties periodically.

Comment: As I understood, it works by specifing some range for each server, eg 1-10000, 10001-20000, 20001-30000, ...
I don't think that identity range would be the best way to do it.
Maybe for my system I can assume there will be max of 10 servers and then go from there. So then my increment will go by 10 on each server, and start value would be in range from 1-10.

Comment: I don't understand your proposal to go by 10 on each server, ranging from 1-10. Can you please elaborate on why the identity range option isn't best for your environment?

Comment: Lets say for example that there is only two servers. On the first server we create empty database, and on the second server we create empty database.
Now on the first database we set every identity key of each table to start from number 1. On the second database we set it to start from number 2.
On each of databases identity will increment by 2. So on db1 there will be (1,3,5,7,9,... to max bigint), and on db2 they will go (2,4,6,8,... to max bigint).

Comment: The good thing with this approach it that we need to do this only once when we create the database. Bad thing is that we don't know if there will be 3,4 or even 10 servers in the future. Thats why I sad that I can assume there is going to be 10 servers so we can have some space to add them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I dare to advise against replication altogether :) it's certainly more pain than fun. If you can afford, look into [Sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753).

Playing with identity is not flexible to say the least. Consider adding moving servers. Identity insert, different schemas and so on.

GUID would be alright for a clustered key if you used newsequentialid() as a default value. It is a bit larger (a number of bits), but it solves the hassle once and for good :)

The way I'd go is to have an int identity clustered key which is only relevant to the database context. Then add a GUID column, which makes sense to the synchronization context. Top it up with a rowversion column to see what's ready for sync.